# How to rewrite the CASE statement into an SSIS expression?

Tags: sql, ssis, case-when

I have the following SQL query that I need to use in a *`Derived Column Transformation`* available in SSIS.

```
CASE WHEN A IN (1,2,3) THEN "ABC"
ELSE "NA" END
```

How do I rewrite this statement into an SSIS expression?

Answer (score 9):

Derived Column Expression Code:

```
A == 1 || A == 2 || A == 3 ? "ABC" : "NA"
```

It will chek if A is equal to 1 or 2 or 3 and if yes, will be "ABC" else "NA".